# Bootstrap nav-collapse toggles once

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, css-transitions, accordion

I have a collapsible menu on a website I'm developing, but the collapse is only toggling through once. I click "MENU" the menu expands, click it again, the menu closes, but won't continue toggling.

Here is a link to my development server. Just resize the browser window until the "MENU" button shows up and click it.

http://www.corporateprdev.com/ymcakpt

Here is my menu structure:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        MENU
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="/ymcakpt/"><img src="/ymcakpt/themes/responsive/images/y-nav-collapse.png" alt="YMCA::Home" longdesc="images/y-nav-collapse.png" align="left" style="margin-right: 15px;"></a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a  href="/ymcakpt/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/ymcakpt/index.php/about/"  >About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/ymcakpt/index.php/membership/"  >Membership</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/ymcakpt/index.php/schedules/"  >Schedules</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/ymcakpt/index.php/contact-us/"  >Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="/ymcakpt/index.php/search/">
          <input name="query" type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style="padding: 2px 8px; margin: 0; width: 210px;">
          <input name="Submit" class="submit" type="image" src="/ymcakpt/themes/responsive/images/go-btn.png" value="Go" style="width: 35px; height: 25px;">
    </form>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your case is a collision between two JavaScript files, namely **bootstrap-transition.js** and **ccm.app.js**.  They are both writing to the jQuery variable `$.support.transition`.  Bootstrap requires that to be an object which includes the property `end` which contains the browser specific event which is fired at the end of a CSS3 transition.  The other file is overwriting the `support.transition` to only be a boolean.

When the `hide` method is called, `transitioning` is set to `true` and because the name of the event which signals the end of the transition is undefined, the `transitioning` property never gets reset to false.  This causes any future calls to `show` or `hide` on the Collapse plugin to short-circuit.

You could try modifying the **ccm.app.js** to be compatible with Twitter Bootstrap's Transitions plugin.  Simply adding a check to not overwrite existing values might suffice.

Another option is trying to ensure that **bootstrap-transition.js** is loaded after **ccm.app.js**.  As long as **ccm.app.js** is only looking for *truthy* values, you should be good.

Comment: I figured it out. Seems I someone my collapse.js file with one from another site I was working on. Reloaded my original file and all is functioning properly now.

Comment: @AnthonyDuncan - You just reverted your file from 2.0.4 to 2.0.1, and the problem which I identified is still there. The only reason you're not seeing the same behavior is because **bootstrap-collapse.js** in 2.0.1 didn't have the short-circuiting feature.  However, because the problem still exists, `shown` and `hidden` events will fail to fire on the page.  I highly encourage you to use the latest version of Bootstrap and fix your issue properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem it was caused by double including of javascript files.

I did **include my library javascript files twice**, when I removed the repeated ones, it is working well.