# Twitter Bootstrap Collapse / Responsive Nav not working in FF / Chrome

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I made a simple responsive page using Twitter Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/5YNmm/3/

The responsive Nav and any collapse toggles work only once in FF and Chrome.
In IE they work perfectly.

The collapse example is copied from the bootstrap site:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Press me to toggle</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse in"> Collapsible Content, initially shown </div>
```

Since i don't include any other js, it shouldn't be the error here [Bootstrap nav-collapse toggles once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959501/bootstrap-nav-collapse-toggles-once) or here [twitter-bootstrap Collapse stops working after first click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231095/twitter-bootstrap-collapse-stops-working-after-first-click), where $.support.transition gets overridden by another library.

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its something in the css files. All I have simply done in this fiddle update is to remove your two css files (that obviously weren't loading on the fiddle)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap_files/stylesheet_427bb03fe1.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap_files/frontend.css" media="all">
```

and replace it with the bootstrap CDN hosted CSS file

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it collapses and expands on chrome and firefox fine now. Fiddle Link here: http://jsfiddle.net/5YNmm/6/

Without any access to the css files I couldn't tell you more - but hopefully this should point you in the right direction!!

Comment: You're right, i nailed it down to that the **component-animations.less was not included**. Adding this made it work.
But even after looking on the Bootstrap page i couldn't find it as a dependency there...

Comment: Bootstrap documentation is notoriously incomplete. Put it up as a pull request on github for the next person :)